# Angular canActivate httpClient infinite loop

Tags: angular, observable, httpclient, infinite-loop, canactivate

I have code like this:

auth.guard.ts

```
canActivate(): void {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refreshToken');

    if (!token || !refreshToken) {
        this.router.navigate('/login');
        return false;
    }

    return this.authService.refresh().pipe(
        map(() => { return true; }),
        catchError(() => {
            this.router.navigate('/login');
            return of(false);
        })
    );
}
```

auth.service.ts

```
refresh(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(
        environment.apiUrl+'/auth/token',
        {
            refreshToken: localStorage.getItem('refreshToken')
        },
        { headers: this.headers }
    );
}
```

But the row "return this.authService.refresh().pipe(" makes infinite loop.

**What could be wrong if I return Angular HttpClient Observable from canActivate() method?**

**What is the reason of infinite loop in this case?**

Comment: why is `canActivate()` return type is set to `void` ? it should be `boolean` or `Observable<boolean>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return this.authService.refresh().pipe(
        take(1),
        switchMap(() => {
            return of(true);
        }),
        catchError(() => {
            this.router.navigate('/login');
            return of(false);
        })
    );
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Change canActivate() to this :

```
canActivate(): boolean {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refreshToken');

    if (!token || !refreshToken) {
        this.router.navigate('/login');
        return false;
    }

    return this.authService.refresh().pipe(
        map(() => return true),
        catchError(() => {
            this.router.navigate('/login');
            return false;
        })
    );
}
```